# Streaming RESTFul Service Response using WebSocket with STOMP

Tags: rest, websocket, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

We are currently using SpringBoot to implement REST services where the response is sent in the form of JSON.
I am exploring the ways to "stream" the response as its a huge response object.
I was exploring WebSocket with STOMP to see how I can use it for my REST Service.
I am having below questions:
1. Using WebSocket with STOMP, can I send the response back to only the caller client (who called the API) and not to broadcast a message to all interested WebSocket clients.
2. Inside the Controller/RESTController class, can I use "same" method to serve both the purposes - HTTP request handling and WebSocket message handling ? Or Do I need to make them 2 seperate method?

Also is there any other way/approach to stream the response. We are using SpringBoot.

Comment: I'm having the same questions, did you figure it out in the end?

Comment: @Autowired SimpMessagingTemplate template; i think you can use this ?